# Is it possible to create (dynamically) different test case for different iteration (Data value) of Data source?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, ui-automation

I have my DataSource in xml file(SumTestData.xml) as show below

```
<Rows>
<Row>
    <A1>1</A1>
    <A2>1</A2>
    <Result>2</Result>
</Row>
<Row>
    <A1>1</A1>
    <A2>2</A2>
    <Result>3</Result>
</Row>
<Row>
    <A1>1</A1>
    <A2>-1</A2>
    <Result>1</Result>
</Row>
```

Now I am using it in my below test method

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("ProjectName\\SumTestData.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML","|DataDirectory|\\SumTestData.xml","Row",DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

public void SumTest()
{

    int a1 = Int32.Parse((string)TestContext.DataRow["A1"]);
    int a2 = Int32.Parse((string)TestContext.DataRow["A2"]);
    int result = Int32.Parse((string)TestContext.DataRow["Result"]);
    ExecSumTest(a1, a2, result);
}
```

When I execute [TestMethod] In Test Explorer I can see only one Test Case, Is it possible to create (dynamically) different test case for different iteration (Data value) of Data source ?
According to my datasource, It has three values, Yes It is very obvious for Test Explorer to consider it as one test case but for me there are three test cases. Is there way to to make or create dynamically test cases which can be seen in test explorer as three test cases instead of one suite , I doubt but hoping for answer here

Answer (score 0):

With MSTest you will always see a single test case for a data driven test method (even with ReSharper in Test Explorer or Unit Test Sessions)

However, if you use NUnit tests, you can see the test cases for each row:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyTests
{
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        private static object[] myDataSource => new object[]
            {
                new object[] { 1, 1, 2 },
                new object[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                new object[] { 1, -1, 1 },
            }

        [TestCaseSource(nameof(myDataSource))]
        public void MyTestMethod(int a1, int a2, int result)
        {
            ExecSumTest(a1, a2, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if all of the arguments are constants, you can use the `TestCase` attribute. You can even define a custom name for the rows:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyTests
{
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        [TestCase(1, 1, 2, TestName = "Custom name of the first row")]
        [TestCase(1, 2, 3)]
        [TestCase(1, -1, 1)]
        public void MyTestMethod(int a1, int a2, int result)
        {
            ExecSumTest(a1, a2, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So any other solution for Test Explorer  ?

Comment: I upvoted you because it was a problem for me as well. Unfortunately MSTest will not show multiple cases for you even in Visual Studio 2015. Maybe it's because the data source can be a database as well and it cannot be evaluated statically but at runtime. NUnit is not just better in that regard but as you can see the data driven tests are much more compact and maintainable. ReSharper supports both MSTest and NUnit, but shows the sub-test cases only for NUnit... :(

Comment: is there any direct/indirect ( wrapper kind of ) solution for Test Explorer?